# Calculate statistic for every possible split of vector in n groups

Tags: r, performance, apply

I would like to use some brute force to calculate custom statistic for every possible split of vector. I figured out how to create all splits (using `partitions` package) and I also managed to calculate what I need. However, my code is slow and I do not see any obvious opportunity to speed it up dramatically. How can I make this faster? The execution time increases exponentially as `obs` (number of rows in data frame) is increasing:

```
#install.packages('partitions', dependencies = TRUE)
library(partitions)

fa <- function(obs) {
# Sample Data
tmpDf <- data.frame(x = seq(obs), 
                    y1 = trunc(runif(obs) * 1000),
                    y2 = trunc(runif(obs) * 1000)
                    )
# Partitions for given data (from 1 up to 9 splits)
partitions <- restrictedparts(obs, 10, include.zero = TRUE)
# Stat for every split
splitsStat <- apply(partitions, 2, function(part) {
  # Calculate indexes of splits based on partitions
  tmp <- cumsum(part[part != 0])
  # Last element is always equal to obs, has to be removed
  tmp <- tmp[-length(tmp)]
  # Add ids of splits to tmpDf data frame
  if(length(tmp) == 0) {
    tmpDf$ints <- 1
  } else if(length(tmp) == 1 ) {
    tmpDf$ints <- ifelse(tmpDf$x > tmp, 1, 0)      
  } else {
    tmpDf$ints <- cut(tmpDf$x, breaks = tmp, labels = FALSE)  
  }
  # I need to aggregate by splits to calculate my statistic
  out  <- aggregate(cbind(y1, y2) ~ ints, data = tmpDf, sum)
  # Calculate statistic
  sum(log(out$y1 / out$y2) * ((out$y1 / sum(out$y1)) - (out$y2 / sum(out$y2))))
  }
)
}

# This takes around a minute to calculate on modern laptop
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  fa(5),  fa(10), fa(15), fa(20), fa(30),  fa(40),  times = 1)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
  fa(5)    11.64077    11.64077    11.64077    11.64077    11.64077    11.64077     1
 fa(10)    70.50710    70.50710    70.50710    70.50710    70.50710    70.50710     1
 fa(15)   318.19676   318.19676   318.19676   318.19676   318.19676   318.19676     1
 fa(20)   890.54962   890.54962   890.54962   890.54962   890.54962   890.54962     1
 fa(30)  6382.75802  6382.75802  6382.75802  6382.75802  6382.75802  6382.75802     1
 fa(40) 29703.39809 29703.39809 29703.39809 29703.39809 29703.39809 29703.39809     1
```

Comment: I suspect `cut()` and `aggregate()` are the culprits.  They are not the fastest functions ever written.  Have you tried `dplyr` and/or `data.table`?

Comment: `obs` is a number of observations in data (number of rows). I have different data frames with same column structure and `obs` (rows) ranging between 10 and 1000. I would like to calculate my statistics for all possible splits up to 10 intervals.

Comment: Yes thanks, my fault .. it should have been clear what `obs` is but I overlooked the function definition.

Comment: The culprit are the function(s) in `library(partitions)`. Not because the package author did a bad job...but It is well known that enumerating partitions is a "hard" task.  In particular doing `restrictedparts(1000,10,blah)` is insane. If you want to speed this up - you will likely have to resort to custom c/c++ code. Your code time will exponentially increase with `obs` size.

Comment: I suggest you attempt to [profile](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) the code. It looks like the main time sucker is the `aggregate()` using a basic `Rprof()` to test the code. (I didn't see `restrictedparts` as causing much trouble).

Comment: It's difficult to answer the question "how do I make this code faster." It's better to take time to describe what you're actually trying to accomplish and then we can compare different solution to yours.

Comment: Once you've definitely identified the bottleneck, you might consider using `parallels` to divvy up the work across your cores (you **do** have a 64-core monster machine, right? :-) )

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
# Partitions for given data (from 1 up to 9 splits)
partitions <- restrictedparts(obs, 10, include.zero = TRUE)
```

returns a matrix with a large number of columns that exponentially increases with `obs`. For small values of `obs`, this is not an issue. But for `obs>100`

```
ncol(restrictedparts(100, 10))
# 6292069

 aa<-restrictedparts(60, 10,include.zero = TRUE)
 microbenchmark(apply(aa,2,sum), times=1)
#Unit: milliseconds
 #             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval

#     apply(aa, 2, sum) 333.3406 333.3406 333.3406 333.3406 333.3406 333.3406     1

 aa<-restrictedparts(100, 10,include.zero = TRUE)
 microbenchmark(apply(aa,2,sum), times=1)
#Unit: seconds
#              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   apply(aa, 2, sum) 27.60511 27.60511 27.60511 27.60511 27.60511 27.60511     1
```

Your execution time will exponentially increase in `obs` if you use this approach (use enumerations of additive integer partitions). Of course, asking `apply` to operate over a large number of columns with a non-trivial function also impacts matters (as comments already mention `cut` and `aggregate` - I am pointing out why the "exponential increase with `obs`" occurs).

Comment: `restrictedparts` takes only 3 secods, the rest (`apply`, `sum`) is what makes it slow.

Comment: @TomasGreif Yes - resulting from `restrictedparts` as It produces xx million columns. As I say in my answer. But the Rcpp approach is good. I use it all the time, for similar things.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the biggest problem was in my approach:

- I need every possible split of a vector where order matters - I have to use `compositions` function. Here, it grows even faster - for 100 elements and 6 splits, there is 71,523,144 possible splits.
- I precalculated value of my function for all possible single split (for 100 elements, this is easily stored in 100x100 matrix, using name `statMat`). From this matrix I can say what is value of my statistics given from/to indices by simple subsetting - I guess this saves a lot of time.
- Now, using generated compositions (for 6 splits, matrix with 6 rows and 71,523,144 columns) I can create cummulative column sums to get index values for splits (this is another Rcpp function).
- Final Rccp function is a for loop where I am just summing results with slightly obscure index definition to get partial function results from precalculated matrix.

It runs on my computer for 6.3 seconds.

Rcpp function:

```
NumericVector part(IntegerMatrix x, NumericMatrix statMat) {
  int nrow = x.nrow();
  int ncol = x.ncol();
  NumericVector out(ncol);
  for (int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
    double total = 0; 
      /* Loop through split vector */
      for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        if(i == 0) {
          /* For first split, we need range from 0 up to split value - 1 (because index)
             starts at 0 */
          total += statMat(0,x(i,j)-1);
        } else {
          /* For next splits, we need range from value of previous split + 1. This is actually
             a value of previous split, as we have indexed shifted by one (ufff). The upper bound
             is value of current split -1 (to adjust index). */
          total += statMat(x(i-1,j),x(i,j)-1);
        }
      }
    out[j] = total;
  }
  return out;
}
```